# Define a range for a plot that contains every fifth row of data

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a scatterplot from a column of numbers, but not every number in the column, but every fifth number (every fifth row). I tried A1:5:A100, but that didn't work. Is there a way to specify a range with "steps" for a plot?

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding an auxiliary column with the numbers 1-5 repeating, and filter this column.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reference such a non-contiguous array directly. But it can be created elsewhere in the sheet, for example

```
=filter(A1:A100, mod(row(A1:A100), 5) = 1)
```

picks the rows 1, 6, 11, 16, ... of the array A1:A100. Then create a scatterplot from that.

Explanation: mod(row(A1:A100), 5) is the remainder of division of the row number by 5. Equating it to 1 gives the rows indicated above. Equate to 0 to get rows 5, 10, 15, 20, ... instead.